# Testing equivalence relation on dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a relation as a list of tuples

```
[(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,1), (2,2), (3,2), (3,3)]
```

I have a dictionary that maps a key to list of its equivalent class

```
{1: [2, 3], 2: [3, 1, 2], 3: [2, 3]}
```

I would like to write a function that, given this dictionary checks if relation is transitive and symmetric, which means

```
∀ a, b, c : if (a,b) ∈ Relation and (b,c) ∈ Relation ==> (a,c) ∈ Relation

∀ a, b : if (a,b) ∈ Relation ==> (b,a) ∈ Relation
```

Is it possible to write this in an efficient way, without abusing nested loops? Using a dictionary is helpful in other parts of the program, but I am not sure if it is here.

Help?

Comment: Do you have any example inputs and expected outputs?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use a dictionary here, because the relations are already easy to work with inside a list of tuples. If you use a dictionary, you would probably still end up converting it to a list of tuples with `d.items()` anyways.

Since these are relations, it really should be a set of tuples, not a list, which can have duplicates:

```
relations = {(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,1), (2,2), (3,2), (3,3)}
```

You can start off by making a function that checks if a relation is transitive:

```
def is_transitive(relation):
    for a, b in relation:
        for c, d in relation:
            # checks transitive property: (a, b) && (b, c) -> (a, c)
            if b == c and (a,d) not in relation:
                return False

    return True
```

Then you can write a function that checks if a relation is symmetric with [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#all):

```
def is_symmetric(relation):
    # checks symmetric property: (a, b) -> (b, a)
    return all(rel[::-1] in relation for rel in relation)
```

Then you can just make a simple function which checks the conjunction of the above two functions:

```
def check_relation(relation):
    # True and True -> True
    # True and False -> False
    # False and True -> False
    # False and False -> False
    return is_symmetric(relation) and is_transitive(relation)
```

Which works as follows (not extensively tested):

```
>>> relations = {(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,1), (2,2), (3,2), (3,3)}
>>> print(check_relation(relations))
False
```